# Reasons for different answers when finding area using Simpsons rule and numerical integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

I have a function $\sqrt{x^4(x+4)}$ to be integrated from 0 up to -4. 
Using Simpson's will give me 19.02 but using normal numerical methods giving me -19.5 !

What's the reason behind this difference in signs?

Comment: Numerical integration algorithms that estimate $\int_a^b f$ tend to assume that a < b. That might be your problem. Also, I didn't get anything even close to 19.5. Are you sure you wrote the function correctly?

Comment: What "normal numerical methods"?

Comment: @StevenGregory Just a small note: the integral indeed evaluates to $-2048/105\approx-19.5$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel. Yep. I calculated $\int_0^4$.

Comment: The function values are all positive, and the coefficients in both methods are all positive, so there is no way on earth you could get a negative answer, without making some bizarre error. And the chances are that if you show your work the error will be obvious to the first person who looks at it. So, show us the calculations you did!

Comment: I say, SHOW US THE CALCULATIONS YOU DID.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is unresponsive.

Answer (score 3):

Try using more segments for your quadrature formula. I've obtained $19.02$ using $h = 1$ step. Or you might have implemented Simpson's rule incorrectly.

Also the integrand is not quite good for numerical integration. Recall that Simpson's rule has a truncation error
$$
\epsilon \sim h^4 \max_{x \in [a,b]} \left|f^{(4)}(x)\right|
$$
and your function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^4 (x+4)} = x^2 \sqrt{x+4}$ has a derivative singularity at $x = -4$. The actual order of convergence will not be $4$, as for smooth functions. Thus methods, like Richardson interpolation or similar, relying on the order of the method, may fail.

Here's a table with Simpson's rule applied to $x^2\sqrt{x+4}$ on $[-4,0]$ with different stepsize $h$. One can determine the *actual* order of convergence $p^*$ which seems to be just $1.5$, not $4$ as for smooth functions.

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
n&h&I_h&\Delta_{h} = |I_{2h} - I_{h}|&p^* = \log_2\frac{\Delta_{2h}}{\Delta_h}&\epsilon^*_h = \frac{\Delta_{h}}{2^{p^*} - 1}\\
\hline
4 &1.00000·10^0 &2.0341983057·10^1 &* &* &*\\
8 &5.00000·10^{-1} &1.9825394258·10^1 &5.16589·10^{-1} &* &*\\
16 &2.50000·10^{-1} &1.9622372473·10^1 &2.03022·10^{-1} &1.35 &1.31448·10^{-1}\\
32 &1.25000·10^{-1} &1.9547084064·10^1 &7.52884·10^{-2} &1.43 &4.43764·10^{-2}\\
64 &6.25000·10^{-2} &1.9519854911·10^1 &2.72292·10^{-2} &1.47 &1.54273·10^{-2}\\
128 &3.12500·10^{-2} &1.9510120947·10^1 &9.73396·10^{-3} &1.48 &5.41578·10^{-3}\\
256 &1.56250·10^{-2} &1.9506660644·10^1 &3.46030·10^{-3} &1.49 &1.90857·10^{-3}\\
512 &7.81250·10^{-3} &1.9505433922·10^1 &1.22672·10^{-3} &1.50 &6.73737·10^{-4}
\end{array}
$$